# Why do `pandas`'s new nullable data types behave differently than other types?

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas`'s nullable types look like other types (compared to the built-in and `numpy` ones).

```
> type(int), type(np.int64), type(pd.Int64Dtype)
(type, type, type)
```

But in order to use them, you can't do it directly likely `pd.Int64Dtype`, but instead like `pd.Int64Dtype()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1.0, 2.0]})
df['x'].astype(int)              # works
df['x'].astype(np.int64)         # works
df['x'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype)    # error
df['x'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())  # works
```

Why do they work this way? And what is the advantage of this design?

Comment: Don't think there is any advantage to it. Just a design decision. You can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/13073534186fb8148d04f925d15e788ec52ed491/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py#L177-L180)